Wants to align numbers in a table in LaTeX
I have this table
 \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Tabel over x- og y-værdier samt middelafstande, kvadratafstande og produktafstande.}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{66BBFF} 
\textbf{} & \textbf{x} & \textbf{$x-m_x$} & \textbf{$(x-m_x)^2$} & \textbf{y} & \textbf{$y-m_y$} & \textbf{$(y-m_y)^2$} & \textbf{$(x-m_x)(y-m_y)$} \\ \hline

\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{1} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0.1cm} 341} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,17cm} 79,45} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 6313,02} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 13,3} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 2,69} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 7,24} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 213,80} \\ \hline

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{2} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,08cm} 270} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,33cm} 8,45} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 71,48} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 10,9} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0,29} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0,08} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 2,46} \\ \hline

\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{3} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,09cm} 241} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,04cm} -20,55} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 422,12} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 10,0} & {\color[HTML]{000000} -0,61} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0,37} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 12,51} \\ \hline

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{4} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,08cm} 237} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,03cm} -24,55} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 602,48} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 9,5} & {\color[HTML]{000000} -1,11} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 1,23} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 27,22} \\ \hline

\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{5} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,09cm} 291} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,16cm} 29,45} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,25cm} 867,57} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 11,5} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0,89} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0,79} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 26,24} \\ \hline

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{6} & {\color[HTML]{000000}  \hspace{0,08cm} 219} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -42,55} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,07cm} 1810,12} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 9,0} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -1,61} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 2,59} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 68,46}  \\ \hline

\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{7} & {\color[HTML]{000000}  \hspace{0,08cm} 225} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -36,55} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,07cm} 1335,57} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 9,1} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -1,51} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 2,28} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 55,15}  \\ \hline

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{8} & {\color[HTML]{000000}  \hspace{0,08cm} 244} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -17,55} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,24cm} 307,84} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 10,4} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -0,21} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 0,04} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 3,67}  \\ \hline

\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{9} & {\color[HTML]{000000}  \hspace{0,08cm} 259} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,22cm} -2,55} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,63cm} 6,48} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 11,1} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 0,49} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 0,24} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -1,25}  \\ \hline

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{10} & {\color[HTML]{000000}  \hspace{0,08cm} 308} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,12cm} 46,45} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,08cm} 2158,02} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 11,8}  & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 1,19} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 1,42} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 55,32}  \\ \hline

\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{11} & {\color[HTML]{000000}  \hspace{0,08cm} 242} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -19,55} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,23cm} 382,02} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 10,1}  & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ -0,51} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 0,26} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \ 9,95}  \\ \hline

\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{66BBFF}\textbf{Sum} & {\color[HTML]{000000}  2877} & {\color[HTML]{000000} \hspace{0,3cm} 0,00} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 14276,73} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 116,7} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 0,00} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 16,55} & {\color[HTML]{000000} 473,55} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab: del1 part 1 opg 1}
\end{table}

And I want the numbers centered, but I also want the numbers to be aligned with the rightmost number in each column. Is there a way to do it besides adding \hspace as I have done with the first two columns, as can be seen in the picture? immag whit manual align numbers to the left
at the moment i have manualy used \hspace which is slow and quat a lot of work (i have a hand ful af tables to eddit)

a) Please don't post code fragments, always make a small, but compilable test file. b) Using , in lengths is not allowed. c) Have a look at the siunitx package. It can do the alignment for you.

in order to allign numbers in you Latex table  you can use the siunitx package, as they already mentioned.
To give you an example:
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{your-caption}
\begin{tabular}{|c|S[table-format=3.0]|S[table-format=2.2]|S[table-format=4.2]|S[table-format=2.1]|S[table-format=1.2]|S[table-format=1.2]|S[table-format=4.2]|}
\hline
...
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

Finally, I recommend to read: misalignment on table numbers Latex
